# add multiple Visual Studio Team Services instances

Tags: azure, tfs

I need to have complete logical segregation between different projects in our VSTS account so that some developers won't be allowed to see projects that they are not assigned to or in a different instance, while others can access all projects.

How can I setup multiple VSTS instances? Will I need another Azure subscription or VSTS account?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need additional VS Team Services accounts. You can create additional Team Projects and configure security for each individual project.

Comment: Yeah, this. Each project in a VSTS instance is separate and distinct. Think of it as one project collection (TFS terminology) with multiple projects. If you require a greater degree of separation for business reasons, then setting up another VSTS instance in your same subscription is an option. You just use the same subscription and provision another instance with a unique name.

Comment: Hi, Jim, I do need a "greater degree of separation for business reasons" but on Azure, I don't have an option to add another instance... there is simply no +ADD button...